# Passing both &mut self and &self to the same function

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Stripped down to the bare essentials, my problematic code looks as follows:

```
pub struct Item;

impl Item {
    /// Partial copy. Not the same as simple assignment.
    pub fn copy_from(&mut self, _other: &Item) {
    }
}

pub struct Container {
    items: Vec<Item>,
}

impl Container {
    pub fn copy_from(&mut self, self_idx: usize, other: &Container, other_idx: usize) {
        self.items[self_idx].copy_from(&other.items[other_idx]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut container = Container { items: vec![Item, Item] };
    container.copy_from(0, &container, 1);
}
```

This is of course rejected by the borrow checker:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `container` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:21:5
   |
21 |     container.copy_from(0, &container, 1);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^---------^^^^----------^^^^
   |     |         |            |
   |     |         |            immutable borrow occurs here
   |     |         immutable borrow later used by call
   |     mutable borrow occurs here

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

I understand why that happens, but I don't have a good solution.

I've considered adding a dedicated `copy_from_self` function that callers need to use in cases where `self == other`:

```
    pub fn copy_from_self(&mut self, to_idx: usize, from_idx: usize) {
        if to_idx != from_idx {
            unsafe {
                let from_item: *const Item = &self.items[from_idx];
                self.items[to_idx].copy_from(&*from_item);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is un-ergonomic, bloats the API surface, and needs `unsafe` code inside.

Note that in reality, the internal `items` data structure is not a simple `Vec`, so any approach specific to `Vec` or `slice` will not work.

Is there an elegant, idiomatic solution to this problem?

Comment: "Is there an elegant, idiomatic solution to this problem?" I can't give you that since you didn't share your true use case, "Note that in reality, the internal items data structure is not a simple Vec". So your question is basically not answerable.

Comment: your `copy_from_self` is probably UB

Comment: @Stargateur Not UB but unsound.

Comment: Extending what @Stargateur said in the above comment, there are two ways to solve this: to split the container (like `<[T]>::split_at_mut()` does, or similarly), this is your solution but you aren't satisfied with it. The other solution is to use interior mutability. But I cannot say more without knowing the real use-case.

Comment: Hmm, sorry for over-simplifying things. The actual data structure is an efficient map from small unsigned integers to values, based on a `Vec<MaybeUninit<T>>` where a `BitVec` tracks which elements are occupied. Why is `copy_from_self` unsound?

Comment: Because of you provide the same index twice and the same container it's UB.

Comment: I added an `if` to check for that case.

Comment: if you explain what you try to do instead we could maybe help you. What is the true purpose of this code. Not what problem you have with borrow checker. I start to understand what you try but it would be better if I doesn't have to guess

Comment: currently I can only answer this https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=602b05a693c16637a898f1422884dc14 the `split` impl depend of the code you didn't show us but still require us to guess

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. But it still requires callers to differentiate between `self == other` and `self != other` in the public API. Would there be any way around that?

Comment: @Stargateur This `split()` is not enough because we need to know which one is `self_idx` and which is `other_idx`.

Comment: You can use `other: impl Into<Option<&'a Item>>`, and, since `Option<T>` impls `From<T>`, it'll help you in the common case where the container is not the same (just pass `&container`). For the other case you'll have to pass `None`, so there is still difference. Also, I don't have a solution to the required unsafety & code growth.

Comment: @Thomas "But it still requires callers to differentiate between self == other and self != other in the public API. Would there be any way around that?" probably not, in fact is probably better to not have this, because, calling method on yourself is different behavior, shouldn't different behavior require different code ? You have the same problem that slice in std, and answer is `split_at()` with it you can call mutate method on one part of the slice with the const part. I don't think there is any other way in Rust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the comments on the question correctly, a general solution seems to be impossible, so this answer is necessarily specific to my actual situation.

As mentioned, the actual data structure is not a `Vec`. If it were a `Vec`, we could use `split_at_mut` to at least implement `copy_from_self` safely.

But as it happens, my actual data structure is backed by a `Vec`, so I was able to add a helper function:

```
    /// Returns a pair of mutable references to different items. Useful if you need to pass
    /// a reference to one item to a function that takes `&mut self` on another item.
    /// Panics if `a == b`.
    fn get_mut_2(&mut self, a: usize, b: usize) -> (&mut T, &mut T) {
        assert!(a != b);
        if a < b {
            let (first, second) = self.items.split_at_mut(b);
            (&mut first[a], &mut second[0])
        } else if a > b {
            let (first, second) = self.items.split_at_mut(a);
            (&mut second[0], &mut first[b])
        } else {
            panic!("cannot call get_mut_2 with the same index {} == {}", a, b);
        }
    }
```

Now we can implement `copy_from_self` without unsafe code:

```
    pub fn copy_from_self(&mut self, to_idx: usize, from_idx: usize) {
        let (to, from) = self.items.get_mut_2(to_idx, from_idx);
        to.unwrap().copy_from(from.unwrap());
    }
```

Comment: I'd prefer returning an `Option` and allowing the caller to handle the equality case, e.g. by panicking with `.unwrap()`.  Also would prefer `match a.cmp(&b)` over the `if...else if...else`.